# UILabel gets clipped when transform applied

Tags: ios, uilabel, uicollectionview, catransform3d

I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewCell` with a horizontally and vertically centered `UILabel`. As the label contains text of different lenght I calculate the width of the label like so. I give it a little margin (10) here to be on the save side.

```c
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = [_collectionViewProvider collectionViewController:self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(MIN(_maxWidth, [text sizeWithFont:self.font].width + 16 + 10), CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.bounds));

    return size;
}
```

As I like to have the users having the impression of a horizontal scroll wheel I apply a transform and adjust the zIndex of the cells depending on the distance from the center. It works almost as expected but as the frame width gets shrinked when the transform is apllied on the far left/right I have the effect that the text gets clipped which looks rather strange.

Here is an image that shows the effect and when the cell is in the center.
Has anybody an idea how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code to calculate the layout.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    CGRect visibleRect = CGRectZero;
    visibleRect.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size = self.collectionView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat activeDistance = floorf(CGRectGetWidth(visibleRect) / 2);
    CGFloat midX = ceilf(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect));
    CGFloat baseAngle = M_PI/180 * 40;
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in array)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, attributes.frame)) {
            CGFloat distance = midX - attributes.center.x;
            attributes.alpha = (activeDistance - ABS(distance))/activeDistance;

            CGFloat value = -distance/activeDistance;
            value *= baseAngle;
            attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(value, 0, 1, 0);

            attributes.zIndex = ABS(distance)/activeDistance * 200;
        }
        else {
            attributes.alpha = 0;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: try to change CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, attributes.frame) to CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, attributes.bounds)

Comment: `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` don't have a bounds property.

Comment: I'm sorry. Try to log parameters: distance; midX; attributes.center.x;